# Form action and post method not working php

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

i have a pay.php script which needs to be executed after an input of an amount. But the file pay.php does not load.

html code:

```
<div class="sap_tabs">
                        <div id="horizontalTab" style="display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0px;">
                            <div class="pay-tabs">
                                <h2>Select Payment Method</h2>
                                  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                                      <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-0" role="tab"><span><label class="pic1"></label>Cash</span></li>
                                      <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab"><span><label class="pic3"></label>Cheque</span></li>
                                      <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-2" role="tab"><span><label class="pic4"></label>Mobile Money</span></li>
                                      <div class="clear"></div>
                                  </ul> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="resp-tabs-container">
                                <div class="tab-1 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-0">
                                    <div class="payment-info">
                                        <h3>Details</h3>
                                        <form method ="post" action"pay.php">
                                            <div class="tab-for">               
                                                <h5>Amount</h5>                                                 
                                                    <input type="text" name = "amount" id ="amount" required />
                                            </div>
                                              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />                                                
                                        </form>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

when i load the file pay.php separately i do not get any issues. 
 but when i enter an amount and click submit the form action does not run or work to insert the data into the database.

php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
 $username="xxxx"; // Mysql username 
 $password="xxxx"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="shipping_pro"; // Database name  
 $tbl_name="payment_cash";

 try {

 //connection 
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shipping_pro', $username, 
  $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $amount = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'amount');
  $sql= "INSERT INTO payment_cash(Amount) VALUES('$amount')";
  if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Payment Received Thank You!.\");
    window.location = \"../dashboard/index.php\"
</script>";
}

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Your problem is here `input type="submit" value="Submit" />` you haven't given it a name. You also are open to SQL injections. You need to parameterize that query.

Comment: Add a name to the submit button, like this <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method ="post" action"pay.php">
```

Should be

```
<form method ="post" action="pay.php">
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Also he have forgot to add a name attribute to the submit button!

Comment: He have added the equal sign right after action attribute action="pay.php"

Comment: @Bleach thank you very much. i feel silly looking at how simple the solution was. the whole day my focus was on the php codes.

Comment: Man, don't think I havent been there!  Happy it is working.

Comment: @JONATHANOKINE In the future you should use the developer console. You can follow the request with that.

Comment: @user3783243 i will look take a look at that in the future.